# No values output to txtField while reading from SQL Server database in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am trying to simply read data from my SQL Server database and input them into text fields on a webform.

I can't figure out what I'm missing but everything compiles smoothly and runs but my text fields remain empty.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String index = Request.Form["indexTb"];

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TravelLogConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);

        string selectSql = "SELECT Location, Date, Message FROM EntryLogs WHERE ID='" + Convert.ToInt32(index) + "'";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader2 = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    reader2.Read();
                    LocTb.Text = (reader2["Location"].ToString());
                    DateTb.Text = (reader2["Date"].ToString());
                    MessTb.Text = (reader2["Message"].ToString());                        
                }

                reader2.Close();
                reader2.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `reader2.Read();` twice - once in the `while` loop, once just below:

```
while (reader2.Read())
{
    reader2.Read();  // <=== WHY call .Read() a second time ?!?!!?!

    LocTb.Text = (reader2["Location"].ToString());
    DateTb.Text = (reader2["Date"].ToString());
    MessTb.Text = (reader2["Message"].ToString());                        
}
```

That's both unnecessary, and could lead to no results being returned.

If your query only returns one row, the `.Read()` in the `while` loop would read that row and return it, but then the next line does another `Read()`, which would not return any data (since the first and only row has already been read).

Just remove that unnecessary second call to  `.Read()` and I bet your data will begin to show up!

And to fix that glaring SQL injection - **use parametrized queries!** as one should **always** do anyway!

```
    string selectSql = "SELECT Location, Date, Message FROM EntryLogs WHERE ID = @Id;";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
    com.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(index);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader2 = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader2.Read())
            {
                // REMOVE THIS reader2.Read();
                LocTb.Text = (reader2["Location"].ToString());
                DateTb.Text = (reader2["Date"].ToString());
                MessTb.Text = (reader2["Message"].ToString());                        
            }

            reader2.Close();
            reader2.Dispose();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I saw the second .read() and removed it in advance , still no return on any values.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @GrenAtta: well - have you **debugged** through your code? Does that SQL `SELECT` actually return any data at all ?? ALso: you should be **extremely careful** to use T-SQL **reserved keywords** like `Date` for your column names - try to avoid this at all costs - call it `SalesDate` or `HireDate` or `EntryDate` whatever else it really is - avoid these very generic names like `Date`....